# how to search mongoose objects that has date which is nested as key value property, How to search date objects within a range of Date?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, meanjs

So I'm trying to find an object from the list of arrays in the mongo object 
Here's what im trying to do... Please ask me if you have any more questions about this issue.

Here's mongo object

```
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5880ebff8239761bbd8703c0"
    },
    "last_date_email_sent_on": "1/23/17",
    "calls_stack": [],
    "dateAdded": "default",
    "FollowUp_Call_Date": {
      "$date": "2017-01-23T17:02:48.220Z"
    },
    "__v": 1
  }
```

Here's the part of Schema

```
  FollowUp_Call_Date: {
    type: Date,
    required: false,
    trim: true
  },
```

Here's my mongoose query to find/ search it.

```
exports.FollowUpSearch = function(req, res, next, id) {

  Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date.$date": {"$gte": new Date(2016, 7, 14) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {  

    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(properties);
    }
  });
};
```

I tried this but it captures all the object that even just has the property FollowUp_Call_Date  attached,  no matter what the value of it is. 
a few objects has date of today i.e jan27, 2017 which shouldnt be searched with this query , but it does.

```
  Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date.$date": {"$gte": new Date(2017, 1, 24), "$lt": new Date(2017, 1, 25) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

[image]

Why is it showign only 2 objects when there is next object i.e Noemi Rota that has same Followup Date ?  ( I know its showing there, but its showing coz of another api call )

Here's the query for this..

```
Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date.$date": {"$gte": new Date(2017, 2, 27) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$date` is a nested property? As I know, it's an internal field used by MongoDB.

Why don't you try:

```
Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date": {"$gte": new Date(2016, 7, 14) }})
```

Comment: I should you exactly how it looks in the json file when i took the backup/ exported the contents.

Comment: It's showing all the properties that has the property of Followup.  even for this query....   even if i dont have any date, for   29 jan, 2017.                                                                                           Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date.$date": {"$gte": new Date(2017, 1, 29) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {

Answer (score 0):

Field names cannot start with `$ ...`

For embedded docs, check with this:

```
Property.find({"FollowUp_call_date":{"date":{"$gte": new Date(2017,1,24)}}})
```

[Find more about embedded doc.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-the-embedded-document)

Comment: Did you changed the field from "$date" to "date"?

Comment: Yes sir, Here's the new query....   Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date.date": {"$gte": new Date(2017, 1, 27) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
Property.find({ "FollowUp_Call_Date": {"$gte": new Date(2017, 0, 27) }}).exec(function(err, properties) {
```